# How can I reverse a jQuery countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a wedding invitation website with a jQuery countdown timer: http://www.sarahoswin.com/

Marriage was on 18 August 2013. Now the timer is showing `00:00:00:00` because the date has passed.

Now I want to display the reverse order of countdown, ie; how many days have gone after the marriage.

Here is my countdown script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
        //custom 'this' selector
        thisEl = $(this);

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed
            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if (settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } 
            else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);
    }
}) (jQuery);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to be the problem.

```
        if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
```

remove it for success.

Comment: thanks for your help.but now the timer 'day value' is getting negative.also all values are decreasing. i want a positive value with increasing.

Comment: The problem was with Math.floor(), should be Math.ceil() because of the negative values. Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TW3vA/

Comment: The solution in jsfiddle does not work for count down, but only does a count up

Comment: @vipin wanted it to be a positive value that increased over time, which this is. I could change it to work both ways if youd like.

Comment: thanks for the solution. but here i want to count up from 18 August 2013 , 11 AM (count from that time).please help me...

Comment: change to:
var eventDate = new Date("18 August, 13 11:00:00");